# I need to fix setInterval so that it only runs my code once every interval - currently runs too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I need to run a function to request data from my API every 60 seconds. The set interval runs every 60 seconds, however it runs the fetch fixtures function multiple times.

Below is the code for my component minus the redux prop and action mapping, and the actual content of the component. Everything works fine besides this setInterval call. Any ideas?

```js
const LiveContest = (props) => {

    //function to fetch fixtures
    const fetchFixtures = async() => {
        let leagueIds = props.leagues.map(league=>{
            return league.intLeagueID
        });

        if(leagueIds.length > 0 & props.sports.length > 0){  
            //api parameters to get fixtures
            let body = {
                leagueIDs: leagueIds,
                start:props.contest.dtmStart,
                end: props.contest.dtmEnd
            }
            const url ='urlplaceholder'
            const options = {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }
            //call api
            const response = await fetch(url, options);
            const fixts = await response.json();
            //organize fixtures and set upcoming + inplay
            let book = organizeUpcomingBook(fixts, props.leagues, props.sports);
            if(_.isEqual(props.book, book) === false){
                props.setBook(book);
            }
            setDisplay(true);
        }
    }
    
        //check book once a minute and remove live games
    setInterval(function(){
        if(!isEmpty(props.contest)){
            console.log('ran once')
            fetchFixtures();    
        }
    }, 60000);
    
    return (
            <>
            </>
        )
        
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LiveContest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code writed within a functional component is executed every rendering.

This means that the `LiveContest` component runs `setInterval` every rendering, which seems to result in multiple data fetches.

Consider using `useEffect`. [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) is the API reperence.

Below is example one.

```
const LiveContest = (props) => {
    // ...

    useEffect(() => {
        const timerId = setInterval(function(){
            if(!isEmpty(props.contest)){
                console.log('ran once')
                fetchFixtures();    
            }
        }, 60000);

        return () => {
          clearInterval(timerId);
        };       

    }, []);

    // ...     

    return ...
}
```

Comment: Also you should add a cleanup function, otherwise you'll have issues with memory leaking

Comment: @aleksa_95 thats what i forgotten. thank u :)

Comment: @aleksa_95 this is the first I am hearing of a cleanup function. Is this specifically used for setInterval, or good practice elsewhere?

Comment: @JustinWade Yes it's a good practice. In your case setInterval would be updating props on unmounted component. No you should not only use it for setInterval. Here's more about it - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup